# What would be the best way to pull search results from any who dot com into an iframe on my website

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe

I like their search and I would like to use it on my website built into a div or iframe... Has anybody done anything similar and what's the best route going fourth? I notice their variables in the GET

http://anywhoyp.yellowpages.com/whitepages?from=AnyWho&fap_terms%5Bfirst%5D=Hunter&fap_terms%5Blast%5D=Thompson&fap_terms%5Bcity%5D=&fap_terms%5Bstate%5D=

Comment: ask them, this is bound to be a breach of their terms otherwise.

Comment: Sounds about right... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Get permission before you iframe external content. If you did iframe that, it would work but the third party could easily prevent it by adding an `X-Frame-Options: DENY` header, which would cause your iframe to stop working.

Comment: Thanks, all relevant information is greatly appreciated.